# Problema con la velocidad de carga

Tags: r

Estoy probando R y aprendiendo a usarlo. Estoy haciendo una aplicacion con shiny cargando los datos desde una base de ORACLE.

Para cargar los datos he creado scripts R a parte de la aplicacion y para lanzarla cargo los datos antes con este scirpt:

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
source("ConexionBBDDOracle.R")
source("sectorAgrupado.R")
source("Sector.R")
source("agrupacionProductoServicio.R")
source("productoservicio.R")
source("consulta.R")
nombresSectorAgrupado <- setNames(object = as.character(sectorAgrupado$L0CODIGO), nm = as.character(sectorAgrupado$L0NOMBRE))
nombresSector <- setNames(object = as.character(sector$SECODIGO), nm = as.character(sector$SENOMBRE))
nombresProductoAgrupado <- setNames(object = as.character(agrupacionproductoservio$E8CODIGO),nm = as.character(agrupacionproductoservio$E8NOMBRE))
nombreProducto <- setNames(object = as.character(productoServicio$PSCODIGO),nm = as.character(productoServicio$PSNOMBRE))

nombresSector <- setNames(object = as.character(sector$SECODIGO), nm = as.character(sector$SENOMBRE))
nombreProducto <- setNames(object = as.character(productoServicio$PSCODIGO),nm = as.character(productoServicio$PSNOMBRE))

runApp(getwd(), port=8100)
```

En los ficheros de los datos tengo informacion de este estilo

```
con <-conexion()
consulta <- ejecutaQuery(con,"select COCODIGO, COTEXTO,COCOSE,COCOPS,COFECHA from L2113T00")

cerrarConexion(con)
```

De esta manera ya tengo los data frames creados para cuando ejecuto la app.

El problema es el siguiente: La tabla de consultas tiene mas de 500.000 registros y quiero cargarla entera. Como tiene bastantes datos tarda mucho en cargar la aplicacion shiny, no solo eso si no que ademas la aplicacion no muestra los datos y se bloquea al rato.

Entiendo que no debiria cargar toda la tabla de golpe porque es inutil. Pero me gustaria saber cual es la forma mas correcta para cargar los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema problema, que era evitar que la tabla tardara demasiado en cargarse lo he conseguido solucionar con la respuesta de https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/9323/jbkunst

El segundo problema consistia en que la aplicacion shiny no mostraba los datos correctamente, la solucion ha sido usar la [libreria DT](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DT/index.html)

E implementando con un par de lineas en el **ui.R**

```
  mainPanel( 
    tabsetPanel(          
      tabPanel('Consulta',DT::dataTableOutput("consulta"))
    )
  )
```

Y otro par en el **server.R**

```
  ##Tabla consultas
  output$consulta <- DT::renderDataTable(
   # consulta[which(consulta$COCOSE == input$selectSector | consulta$COCOPS == input$selectPro)]
    DT::datatable(consulta,options = list(pageLength = 25))
    )
```

De esta manera la aplicacion ya no se bloquea, siga tardando un poco en cargar pero el cambio es mas que notorio

Answer (score 1):

Un tip que uso en este tipo de eventos cuando la descarga (posiblemente desde un lugar remoto) dura mucho es:

```
nombre_data <- "consulta.rds" 

if(file.exists(nombre_data)) {
   # si existe previamente lo cargamos
   consulta<- readRDS(nombre_data)
} else {
  # en caso que no exista lo debemos cargar
  # crear conexión, etc.
  consulta<- ejecutaQuery(con,"select COCODIGO, COTEXTO,COCOSE,COCOPS,COFECHA     from L2113T00")

  # y salvamos para una proxima oportunidad
  saveRDS(consulta, nombre_data)

}
```

Con eso lo guardamos localmente la primera vez y en una proxima oportunidad lo cargamos desde el archivo local.

Obviamente eso es útil en caso de que la consulta no cambie por fecha de ejecucción, con esto hablo de ejemplos donde la tabla cambia diariamente.

También es recomendable:

- Descargar las columnas realmente necesarias, pero asumo que esto ya lo estás haciendo
- En caso de que los necesites resumidos, es preferible darle el trabajo a la bbdd y así minimizar la cantidad de informacíon a transferir/descargar.

Comment: Hola, lo primero es que la app se carga notablemente mas rapido, pero hay un par de cosas que estan mal. La primera es una simple errata en el codigo que me has pasado pero no me deja editarlo porque para editar tienen que ser mas de 6 caracteres los que cambies. El codigo corrercto es ´file.exists´ con "S" al final. La segunda es que cuando recojo los valores desde el archivo me lo guarda como una funcion y no un data frame.

Comment: Ya esta, solucionado. Gracias por tu ayuda al final parte de tu respuesta era valida, me lo guardaba como funcion porque me habia equibocado en una variable, luego he tenido que hacer un pager en la app shiny.

Comment: Disculpa :) por el error. Que bueno que haya mejorado algo el tiempo de carga. Saludos,